# MDL radio button with images and not labels

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button, material-design

I have to create mdl radio button which looks like this:
[radio button with image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2nNS.jpg)

This component/div should change background-colour and image and text-color on selection/deselection. I am not able to achieve this and I have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out.

Help me please. This is what I have tried so far but nothing is working:

```
<div class="display-contents-inline margin-bottom">

    <input type="radio" id="android" class="mdl-radio__button margin-right" name="options" checked />
    <span>
      <div class="tab-data data-windows-server  display-contents-inline">
        <div>
          <img src="./components/package-setup/img/windows-server-selected.png">
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>{{i18n.WindowsServer}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

and

```
input[type='radio']:checked + .data-windows-server {
  background-color: #01579b;
}
```

Comment: Will you setup a fiddle or codepen? I doubt that's an image though, it's an html button with custom windows/linux icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be missing span:
input[type='radio']:checked + span > .data-windows-server {